# How to use iRedMail's LDAP database for user authentication?

Tags: linux, ssl, openldap, user-accounts, email-server

I have a few servers set up and I'd like to centralize access for users using LDAP. I have my primary server that is hosting email using iRedMail, and there already happens to be an LDAP database that was set up with iRedMail. Now, I'd like for my user accounts to be tied to their email accounts (for example, changing their email password also changes their password on servers they have access to). I've done some searching (DuckDuckGoing?) for how to use iRedMail's LDAP database as a user authentication database for UNIX accounts, but I've yet to find anything remotely helpful. Anyone ever done this have any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I figured it out. Here's a quick and dirty guide on how I got it done:

1. First, iRedMail automatically generates an SSL certificate on install. If your hostname is not what you want the CN for the cert to be, then you're going to need to generate a new SSL cert. Actually, I'd do this regardless. Here's how to accomplish step one:

   ```
   $ cd iRedMail-0.8.5/tools
   $ vi generate_ssl_keys.sh

   # Modify the following line
   export HOSTNAME="*.yourdomain.com" # I created a wildcard cert

   # Set the rest (e.g., TLS_COUNTRY) to match your information
   ```
2. Now we need to generate our SSL certs:

   ```
   $ sh generate_ssl_keys.sh
   $ mv certs/iRedMail_CA.pem /etc/pki/tls/certs/
   $ mv private/iRedMail.key /etc/pki/tls/private/
   ```
3. At this piont I rebooted my system. It was easier for me than restarting a bunch of services.
4. Now, before we move to our LDAP clients, we need to make some changes to our LDAP server. The first change we will make is to add unixHomeDirectory to the posixAccount objectclass. The reason: I did not want my users being stuck in the homeDirectory that iRedMail associates with their account.

   ```
   $ vi /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema

   # Add the following under attributetype nisMapEntry (1.3.6.1.1.1.1.27)
   attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.28 NAME 'unixHomeDirectory'
       DESC 'The absolute path to the users home directory'
       EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match
       SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )

   # Associate unixHomeDirectory with the posixAccount objectclass
   objectclass ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.0 NAME 'posixAccount'
       DESC 'Abstraction of an account with POSIX attributes'
       SUP top AUXILIARY
       MUST ( cn $ uid $ uidNumber $ gidNumber $ homeDirectory )
       MAY ( userPassword $ loginShell $ gecos $ unixHomeDirectory $ description ) )
   ```
5. Now we are going to add an obMemberOf attribute for our users. This will be used later with sssd.

   ```
   $ vi /etc/openldap/schema/iredmail.schema

   # I added this under listAllowedUser attributetype (1.3.6.1.4.1.32349.1.2.3.3)
   attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.32359.1.2.3.4 NAME 'obMemberOf'
       DESC 'Distinguished name of a group of which the object is a member'
       EQUALITY distinguishedNameMatch
       SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.12 )

   # And then I associated it with the objectclass mailUser
   objectclass ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.32349.1.2.4.3 NAME 'mailUser'
       DESC 'Mail User' SUP top AUXILIARY
       MUST ( mail $ uid )
       MAY ( storageBaseDirectory $ mailMessageStore $ homeDirectory $
             userPassword $ mailHost $ mailUID $ mailGID $
             mailQuota $ mailQuotaMessageLimit $
             mailForwardingAddress $ shadowAddress $ accountStatus $
             userRecipientBccAddress $ userSenderBccAddress $
             enabledService $ telephoneNumber $ backupMailAddress $
             mtaTransport $ memberOfGroup $ expiredDate $
             lastLoginDate $ lastLoginIP $ lastLoginProtocol $
             preferredLanguage $ disclaimer $ accountSetting $
             title $ userManager $
             mailWhitelistRecipient $ mailBlacklistRecipient $
             domainGlobalAdmin $ obMemberOf ))
   ```
6. I made the following changes to /etc/openldap/slapd.conf

   ```
   # Comment out disallow bind_anon
   # Disallow bind as anonymous.
   #disallow    bind_anon

   # Uncommented this line
   # Uncomment below line to allow binding as anonymouse.
   allow bind_anon_cred

   #
   access to dn.regex="cn=[^,]+,dc=domain,dc=com"
         by anonymous                    auth
         by self                         write
         by users                        none

   # Added these two lines
   access to dn.exact=""
         by * read

   # And these two
   access to dn.exact="cn=Subschema"
        by * read

   # And gave anonymous read access
   # Set default permission.
   access to *
       by anonymous                    read
       by self                         write
       by users                        read
   ```
7. Now I went to https://www.mydomain.com/iredadmin and added a user. After adding the user, an ldapsearch returns the following:

   ```
   # user1@mydomain.com, Users, mydomain.com, domains, mydomain.com
   dn: mail=user1@mydomain.com,ou=Users,domainName=mydomain.com,o=domains,dc=mydomain,dc=com
   objectClass: inetOrgPerson
   objectClass: mailUser
   objectClass: shadowAccount
   objectClass: amavisAccount
   mail: user1@mydomain.com
   userPassword:: XXX
   uid: user1
   storageBaseDirectory: /var/vmail
   mailMessageStore: vmail1/mydomain.com/d/a/w/user1-2013.11.19.17.43.46/
   homeDirectory: /var/vmail/vmail1/mydomain.com/d/a/w/user1-2013.11.19.17.43.46/
   enabledService: mail
   enabledService: deliver
   enabledService: lda
   enabledService: smtp
   enabledService: smtpsecured
   enabledService: pop3
   enabledService: pop3secured
   enabledService: imap
   enabledService: imapsecured
   enabledService: managesieve
   enabledService: managesievesecured
   enabledService: sieve
   enabledService: sievesecured
   enabledService: forward
   enabledService: senderbcc
   enabledService: recipientbcc
   enabledService: internal
   enabledService: lib-storage
   enabledService: shadowaddress
   enabledService: displayedInGlobalAddressBook
   shadowLastChange: 0
   amavisLocal: TRUE
   mailQuota: 0
   cn: Good User
   givenName: user1
   sn: user1
   preferredLanguage: en_US
   employeeNumber: Application Developer
   accountStatus: active
   ```
8. As we can see, everything to make this a posixAccount is missing. So, that's what we're going to do:

   ```
    $ vi /tmp/user1.modify
    # Now, I create a file called /tmp/user1.modify that looks like this
    dn: mail=user1@mydomain.com,ou=Users,domainName=mydomain.com,o=domains,dc=mydomain,dc=com
    changetype: modify
    add: objectClass
    objectClass: posixAccount
    -
    add: loginShell
    loginShell: /bin/bash
    -
    add: uidNumber
    uidNumber: 2006
    -
    add: gidNumber
    gidNumber: 2006
    -
    add: unixHomeDirectory
    unixHomeDirectory: /home/user1
   ```
9. And we run ldapmodify to add the attributes to the account

   ```
   ldapmodify -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=mydomain,dc=com" -W -f /tmp/user1.modify
   ```
10. Now I create an LDAP group.

    ```
    vi /tmp/devgroup.ldif

    # Paste the following in there
    dn: cn=developers,ou=Groups,domainName=mydomain.com,o=domains,dc=mydomain,dc=com
    objectClass: posixGroup
    objectClass: top
    cn: developers
    userPassword:: {crypt}x
    gidNumber: 1500
    memberUid: user1

    # And add to LDAP
    ldapadd -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=mydomain,dc=com" -W -f /tmp/devgroup.ldif
    ```
11. Add user1 as an obMemberOf the developers group

    ```
     vi /tmp/user1.modify

     # It should now look like this
     dn: mail=user1@mydomain.com,ou=Users,domainName=mydomain.com,o=domains,dc=mydomain,dc=com
     changetype: modify
     add: obMemberOf
     obMemberOf: cn=developers,ou=Groups,domainName=mydomain.com,o=domains,dc=mydomain,dc=com

     # Run ldapmodify
     ldapmodify -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=mydomain,dc=com" -W -f /tmp/user1.modify
    ```
12. At this point we have user1, two custom attributes (obMemberOf, unixHomeDirectory), and an LDAP group for developers. It's now time to set up a few clients. The first client I set up was running Ubuntu 12.04 server. Here are the steps for that client:

    ```
      # First install all the relevant packages
      $ apt-get install ldap-utils libpam-ldap libnss-ldap nslcd

      # I need the SSL cert from my iRedMail host
      scp user@mydomain.com:/etc/pki/tls/certs/iRedMail_CA.pem /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem

      # Now we configure the LDAP client
      $ vi /etc/ldap.conf

      # Here's what my ldap.conf ended up looking like:
      # BEGIN /etc/ldap.conf
      host ldap.mydomain.com
      base dc=mydomain,dc=com
      ldap_version 3
      # You can user cn=Manager,dc=yourdomain,dc=com if you'd like. iRedMail sets up this vmail account as read-only, so I went with that instead.
      rootbinddn cn=vmail,dc=mydomain,dc=com
      pam_password ssha
      nss_base_passwd ou=Users,domainName=mydomain.com,o=domains,dc=mydomain,dc=com
      nss_base_shadow ou=Users,domainName=mydomain.com,o=domains,dc=mydomain,dc=com
      nss_base_group ou=Groups,domainName=mydomain.com,o=domains,dc=mydomain,dc=com
      nss_map_attribute homeDirectory unixHomeDirectory
      pam_login_attribute uid
      ssl start_tls
      tls_checkpeer yes
      tls_cacertfile /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
      # END /etc/ldap.conf

      # Create file /etc/ldap.secret and put the plain text password for your rootbinddnn in there, then 'chmod 600 /etc/ldap.secret (root:root ownership).

      # Next I edit /etc/nslcd.conf. Here is that file
      # BEGIN /etc/nslcd.conf
      uid nslcd
      gid nslcd
      uri ldap://ldap.mydomain.com
      base dc=mydomain,dc=com
      ldap_version 3
      ssl start_tls
      tls_reqcert demand
      tls_cacertfile /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
      # END /etc/nslcd.conf

      # Now I edit /etc/ldap/ldap.conf and add the following line to the bottom
      # It is the only uncommented line in the file
      TLS_CACERT    /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem

      # My PAM files look as follows

      # BEGIN /etc/pam.d/common-account
      account   [success=2 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]    pam_unix.so 
      account   [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_ldap.so 
      account   requisite           pam_deny.so
      account   required            pam_permit.so
      # END /etc/pam.d/common-account

      # BEGIN /etc/pam.d/common-auth
      auth  [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
      auth  [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
      auth  requisite           pam_deny.so
      auth  required            pam_permit.so
      # END /etc/pam.d/common-auth

      # BEGIN /etc/pam.d/common-password
      password  [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure sha512
      password  [success=1 user_unknown=ignore default=die] pam_ldap.so try_first_pass
      password  requisite           pam_deny.so
      password  required            pam_permit.so
      # END /etc/pam.d/common-password

      # BEGIN /etc/pam.d/common-session
      session   [default=1]         pam_permit.so
      session   requisite           pam_deny.so
      session   required            pam_permit.so
      session       optional            pam_umask.so
      session   required                    pam_unix.so 
      session   optional            pam_ldap.so 
      session   optional                    pam_systemd.so 
      session required pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0022
      # END /etc/pam.d/common-session

      # I then edit /etc/nsswitch.conf and added ldap at the end of the passwd, group and shadow lines
      passwd:         compat ldap
      group:          compat ldap
      shadow:         compat ldap

      # Enable the service and restart it
      $ update-rc.d nslcd enable
      $ /etc/init.d/nscd restart

      # Test things out
      $ gnutls-cli --x509cafile /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem ldap.mydomain.com
      $ ldapsearch -H"ldap://ldap.mydomain.com" -D "cn=vmail,dc=mydomain,dc=com" -b "dc=mydomain,dc=com" -W -d-1 -Z 
      $ getent passwd
      $ id user1

      # You should now be able to su to user1 and ssh in as user1.
    ```
13. The next client I set up was a CentOS 6.4 server running sssd.

    ```
      # Install the relevant packages
      $ yum install openldap-clients sssd
      $ chkconfig sssd on

      # For now I set SELinux to permissive
      $ echo 0 > /selinux/enforce

      # scp  my cert over
      $ scp user@mydomain.com:/etc/pki/tls/certs/iRedMail_CA.pem /tmp
      $ scp user@mydomain.com:/etc/pki/tls/private/iRedMail.key /tmp

      # combine the two certs
      $ awk 'FNR==1{print ""}1' /tmp/iRedMail.key /tmp/iRedMail_CA.pem > /etc/openldap/cacerts/iRedMail_CA.pem
      $ cacertdir_rehash /etc/openldap/cacerts/

      # Enable sssd.
      $ authconfig --enableldap --enableldapauth --ldapserver=ldaps://ldap.mydomain.com --ldapbasedn="dc=mydomain,dc=com" --update

      # I modified my /etc/sssd.conf file to look like this:
      [sssd]
      config_file_version = 2
      services = nss, pam
      domains = LDAP
      [nss]
      filter_users = root,named,avahi,haldaemon,dbus,radiusd,news,nscd

      [pam]

      [domain/LDAP]
      ldap_search_base = dc=mydomain,dc=com
      ldap_access_filter = obMemberOf=cn=developers,ou=Groups,domainName=mydomain.com,o=domains,dc=mydomain,dc=com
      id_provider = ldap
      auth_provider = ldap
      chpass_provider = ldap
      access_provider = ldap
      ldap_schema = rfc2307
      ldap_uri = ldap://ldap.mydomain.com
      ldap_user_name = uid
      ldap_user_home_directory = unixHomeDirectory
      ldap_user_search_base = ou=Users,domainName=mydomain.com,o=domains,dc=mydomain,dc=com
      ldap_group_search_base = ou=Groups,domainName=mydomain.com,o=domains,dc=mydomain,dc=com
      ldap_default_bind_dn = cn=vmail,dc=mydomain,dc=com
      ldap_default_authtok_type = password
      ldap_default_authtok = p4ssw0rd
      enumerate = true
      cache_credentials = true
      ldap_tls_reqcert = never
      ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/openldap/cacerts

      # Start sssd in the foreground with debugging on.
      $ /usr/sbin/sssd -i -d7

      # Open another terminal and do the following
      $ getent passwd
      $ id user1
      $ ssh user1@localhost
      $ su - user1

      # Check the other terminal for any errors and fix as necessary.
      # If no errors... break the sssd process with Ctrl+C
      $ service sssd start
    ```

Here are some of the errors I ran into during this process and what I did to fix each of them.

> Warning: LDAP access rule 'filter' is set, but no ldap_access_filter configured. All domain users will be denied access.

This is why I added the LDAP group on my server and the obMemberOf attribute. I then used it on the sssd client as my ldap_access_filter (i.e., anyone who has attribute obMemberOf set to the DN for the development group has access to the system.

> TLS: skipping 'iRedMail_CA.pem' - filename does not have expected format (certificate hash with numeric suffix)

Running 'cacertdir_rehash /etc/openldap/cacerts/' seemed to fix things. It created a symlink (the certificates hash with numeric suffix) that points to iRedMail_CA.pem

I ran into quite a few other errors (A plethora of "Invalid Credentials," "Access Denied," and other access related errors). I will update this later to cover them as well.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether you can configure sssd to use a flexible ldap filter and lookup different (non-default) ldap attributes in this case.

If you modified iRedMail LDAP schema file, you should pay attention to sync this schema with upstream.